# Can CSMA/CD in ethernet tell the sender when the client has gotten a packet that is "damaged"?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

If a client receives a damaged packet then it will know that after comparing the packet's checksum to the one in the header.
But can a sender know when a packet has reached the client in a damaged form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems you are making a confusion. `CSMA/CD` is for detecting when somebody else is using the link so that a collision doesn't happen. It's its only purpose.

Second, ethernet senders cannot find out if the frame they sent arrives malformed. There is no acknowledgement. The upper-layer protocols must take precautions.